# C# looping over directories and needing to get datetime of files along with order them by grouping of file names and order by timestamp

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

I am trying to loop over a directory that contain subdirectories in which I limit the directories I want to go into with searching for the directory creationtime.

Now,  I need to be able to order and group by files by 2 criteria,   1.  Timestamp on file   2. Files by ascending order

Currently this is how I am looping the Directory

```
//root folder
var txtFileToImportFromPath = @"\\sbc\svabc2\";
var listFolderNames = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(txtFileToImportFromPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

//only search files from 5-6-2017 to 5-12-2017
var dt = new DateTime(2017,5,6,0,0,0);
var dt2 = new DateTime(2017,5,12,0,0,0);

if (listFolderNames.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var currentFolder in listFolderNames)
    {
        if (new DirectoryInfo(currentFolder).CreationTime > dt && new DirectoryInfo(currentFolder).CreationTime < dt2)
        {
            //I ONLY want .txt files
            // This does not seem effective as in the loop  "file" seems to have no date...
            foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(currentFolder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file.Length);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Seems that I am successful with getting Directory information and looping the directories,  but it is the files that I am wanting to get the order of the file by its name and timestamp etc..

Example of file names

```
file name                             Date modified 

waterview_119431.txt                   5/6/2017  11:49 AM
waterview_111274284720170513.txt       5/6/2017  11:49 AM
```

I know that in my final loop I want to order by date and time modified along with the client name ascending,  because then I will be able to tell which file is of a certain type by the file length

Should I use some other object or utility?  FileInfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use could use DirectoryInfo to enumerate over the directories and files:

```
        var txtFileToImportFromPath = @"\\sbc\svabc2\";
        var listFolderNames = new DirectoryInfo(txtFileToImportFromPath);

        // only search files from 5-6-2017 to 5-12-2017
        var dt = new DateTime(2017, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0);
        var dt2 = new DateTime(2017, 5, 12, 0, 0, 0);

        List<FileInfo> allRelevantFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
        foreach (var currentFolder in listFolderNames.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (currentFolder.CreationTime <= dt || currentFolder.CreationTime >= dt2) continue;

            // only take top directory, otherwise you would get duplicates
            var files = currentFolder.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            // add to all
            allRelevantFiles.AddRange(files);
        }

        var ordered = allRelevantFiles.OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime).ThenBy(x => x.Name);
        foreach (var fileInfo in ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{fileInfo.Name}\t{fileInfo.LastWriteTime}");
        }
```

It was not clearly if you want to have the files ordered over alle directories or for each directory. I implemented the second (collecting alle files and then order).